# compiling cuda file in makefile error

Tags: makefile, cuda, nvcc

I have made a makefile in order to compile my files:

```
CFLAGS        = -O3 -Wall -I /usr/local/cuda/include/ 
NVCCFLAGS     = -O3 -arch sm_20
LDFLAGS       = -O3 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
EXE           =  runAPP

app.o:app.cu
$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIB_PATH) $(LDFLAGS) $@

$(EXE): app.o 
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@  $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIB_PATH) app.o  \
        -lANN_char -lz
    cp $@ ../bin
```

But I got this problem:

app.cpp:26:26: error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
app.cpp:27:18: error: cuda.h: No such file or directory

This is how I include them in the app.cpp:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

Why is this problem?

I search something on google, they said that the app.cpp must be always app.cu, is it true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have shown no compilation rule for `app.o`. How is it compiled to an object?

Comment: The makefile you have shown is only describing how to build `runApp` by linking `app.o` and some libraries. But you have not shown the build rule for `app.o`. I am asking you to show me it.

Comment: app.o: app.cu
$(NVCC) -c %< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

Comment: I just added that but I got: missing separator

Comment: please edit the question to show the actual makefile and the actual errors.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your makefile, you have:

`CFLAGS        = -O3 -Wall -I /usr/local/cuda/include/ 
NVCCFLAGS     = -O3 -arch sm_20
LDFLAGS       = -O3 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
EXE           =  runAPP`

app.o:app.cu
$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -c $< -o **$(CPPFLAGS)** $(LIB_PATH) $(LDFLAGS) $@

CPPFLAGS should be expanding to nothing; try changing it to CFLAGS, or change CFLAGS to CPPFLAGS.

Comment: No problem.  Had my share of those moments myself.  :)